# Calculate nearest town for 2900 lot centroids

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity, centroids, large-datasets

I have 16 town point shapefiles.
I have a layer of 2900 centroids for lots.

I need to determine the nearest town for each of the centroids.

The option I came up with is to Split by Attribute by name, thus creating 2900 point layers for the centroids, then doing the Near tool for each centroid. This will take a long time and may even crash ArcMap. There is probably a script for it, but I am very new to python.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a script.

1. Start by [merging](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/merge.htm) all the towns into one point feature class.
2. [Generate Near Table](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm) with Lots as `input_features` and the merged Towns as `near_features`:

> Calculates distances and other proximity information between features
>   in one or more feature class or layer. Unlike the Near tool, which
>   modifies the input, Generate Near Table writes results to a new
>   stand-alone table and supports finding more than one near feature.

3. Join Towns to the Near Table.
4. Join the resulting table to the Lots
5. Export to a new feature class

You will now have a feature class of all the lots with information about the closest Town.

Comment: Do you know why the Near Table came out blank?

Comment: No you probably did something wrong. Are the feature classes in the same coordinate system? You could also try on a selection of you data.

Comment: I got the Table to work - changed the coordinate system - thank you. But how do I add the Towns to the Near Table when there are only 17 features and 2900 in the Near Table?

Comment: @AmyBoddah if you dont need the distance information you could do Spatial Join with match option closest

Comment: Ok nice. You need to join them together. Right click the table and then join